# How to fix grub menu item for Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, grub-efi

TL;DR both Ubuntu and Windows boot fine from f8 and grub menu once upon a time. I decided to upgrade Win10 from slow HDD to SDD, and then Windows Boot Manager gave me two Win10 options. I reformatted the old HDD because I didn't need two win10, and that's when grub menu stop booting into Windows. Even so f8 menu still boots both OSes fine.

Not entirely sure how to explain my problem, I'll try my best. Been running Ubuntu 20.04 from a 1TB SSD for a few months, I decided to install Win10 on an old 500 GB HDD. I noticed the Win10 installer didn't create its own EFI on the HDD, but rather created its boot entry in the main 1TB SSD efi partition along with Ubuntu efi. Not sure if most people have one EFI partition per drive or per system, but either way Win10 installer didn't really have any options for this. Booted on Ubuntu to update the grub menu, and then a Windows Boot Manager menu item was added. Things worked great every menu item on grub worked fine.

Fast forward to now I installed a new Win10 on a new 1TB SSD, since the old HDD was too slow on boot and response. Things worked good, but on grub menu when I launched Windows Boot Manager I now had two Windows OS options. I decided to reformat the old HDD so when I selected Windows Boot Manager it would boot straight into the new Win10 rather than seeing two options.

That was a big mistake, now I could not boot into any Windows either from F8 boot options, or grub menu. I popped the installer to boot cmd prompt, then ran `bootrec` commands and I was able to boot into Windows 10 with F8. Also if I put Windows Boot Manager as the first boot option, the new Win10 OS launches with no problems. I thought all things would be fixed by now. I put Ubuntu back to boot option 1, I select Windows Boot Manager from grub menu and Windows 10 boots fine only once, any subsequent tries gives me a blue screen of RECOVERY everytime about a device not found error code 0x000000e.

I've tried all kinds of things, efibootmgr, boot-repair, update-grub, I've look at the UUID and it seems to be correct for Windows Boot Manager.

The biggest question is that I don't know what's broke, windows boots fine, so it leads me to believe the grub menu is broken, but I thought grub just uses efi entries, but then I don't understand how Windows still boots fine.

bcdedit:

```
Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {9dea862c-5cdd-4e70-acc1-f32b344d4795}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume3
path                    \EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-US
default                 {d0fb23a8-0a09-11eb-9dac-82074bc046f4}
resumeobject            {928ea8ee-0a01-11eb-8113-806e6f6e6963}
displayorder            {d0fb23a8-0a09-11eb-9dac-82074bc046f4}
timeout                 30

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {d0fb23a8-0a09-11eb-9dac-82074bc046f4}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.efi
description             Windows 10 Pro
locale                  en-US
recoverysequence        {d0fb23a9-0a09-11eb-9dac-82074bc046f4}
recoveryenabled         Yes
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {928ea8ee-0a01-11eb-8113-806e6f6e6963}
bootmenupolicy          Standard
```

efibootmgr:

```
~ ❯❯❯ efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 000C
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 000C,0000,000D,0009,000A,0004,0005,0001,0002,0003
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,f00bcd52-36bd-4a75-9dc8-098d39d94539,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}....................
Boot0001* UEFI:CD/DVD Drive     BBS(129,,0x0)
Boot0002* UEFI:Removable Device BBS(130,,0x0)
Boot0003* UEFI:Network Device   BBS(131,,0x0)
Boot0004  UEFI: PXE IP4 Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (7) I219-V PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1f,0x6)/MAC(a85e45e7f8fa,0)/IPv4(0.0.0.00.0.0.0,0,0)..BO
Boot0005  UEFI: PXE IP6 Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (7) I219-V PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1f,0x6)/MAC(a85e45e7f8fa,0)/IPv6([::]:<->[::]:,0,0)..BO
Boot0009  UEFI: PXE IP4 Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (7) I219-V PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1f,0x6)/MAC(a85e45e7f8fa,0)/IPv4(0.0.0.00.0.0.0,0,0)..BO
Boot000A  UEFI: PXE IP6 Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (7) I219-V PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1f,0x6)/MAC(a85e45e7f8fa,0)/IPv6([::]:<->[::]:,0,0)..BO
Boot000C* ubuntu        HD(1,GPT,f00bcd52-36bd-4a75-9dc8-098d39d94539,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\UBUNTU\SHIMX64.EFI)
Boot000D* UEFI: PNY USB 2.0 FD 1100, Partition 1        PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(7,0)/HD(1,GPT,9ea75237-6b11-4b0b-ad58-54fe8ebe30ba,0x800,0x1df2edf)..BO
```

Both SSD drives info with lsblk:

```
Disk /dev/nvme1n1: 931.53 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: Samsung SSD 970 EVO Plus 1TB            
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: D38640D2-C120-4733-A4F8-9B4F1FFE7138

Device         Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme1n1p1  2048      34815      32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme1n1p2 34816 1953523711 1953488896 931.5G Microsoft basic data


Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 931.53 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: Sabrent Rocket Q                        
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 041DB30D-EAB3-460B-A8EC-F056C3B33024

Device           Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1    2048    1050623    1048576  512M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2 1050624 1953523711 1952473088  931G Linux files
```

efi part info with blkid:

```
/dev/nvme0n1p1: UUID="8505-DD3A" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="f00bcd52-36bd-4a75-9dc8-098d39d94539
```

Comment: I think I might have found the issue hibernation and fast boot seems to be locking the windows hdd.

Comment: Most likely hibernation since fast boot was enabled before and didn't cause any problems. Will monitor for a few days but reboot and shutdown to grub menu boots Windows fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I found Windows partition was locked. I was in the process of restoring EFI partition with clonezilla pre-windows installation. I noticed clonezilla saying could not read Windows partition due to hybernation or fast boot. Didn't pay much attention to it since I was focused on the ESP partition.

Then I re installed Windows 10. To my surprise I was still getting BSOD with grub menu, but not F8. That's when I checked Windows hybernation setting and fast boot on uefi settings. And then Win10 from grub menu booted fine both on restart or after shutdown.

Three days troubleshooting because Windows locks the drive during shutdown.